# Apache, Symfony2 и права пользователей (linux)

Tags: linux, apache, xubuntu

В общем у меня следующая проблема, не выходит нормально поставить Symfony2 приложение на виртуальный хост апача, суть в следующем: Запустить апач от именю моего пользователя у меня не получается, поэтому запускаю через sudo:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Так вот, после того как я чищу кеш командой:

```
sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=dev(либо prod)
```

в папке cache создаются некотоые файли, причем создаются они от имени того пользователя, от которого запущен apache, следовательно во владельцах файла написано root(root), когда я запрашиваю сайт, я получаю ошибку о том что файл в папке cache не может быть прочитан. Приходится каждый раз писать:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/projectname/app/cache
```

Добавляя тем самым группу владельцев www-data чтобы сайт открылся корректно. И так каждый раз, после каждой чистки кеша. Помимо этого в prod окружении почему-то 1. Слетают стили (sass) 2. Открыть его, как и dev окружение можно только перейдя по адресу projectname/app(_dev соответственно).php, в противном случае (если ввести просто projectname) мне показывается содержимое директории web, как будто бы не установлен DirectoryIndex app.php (хотя он установлен в .htaccess), под окружением dev со стилями всё в порядке.

Кстати, если запустить приложение под встроенным в PHP сервером из под Symfony

```
php app/console server:start
```

то всё работает идеально. Но я хочу научиться работать с апачем. Как разрулить все эти дела с пользователями и правами доступа, в линуксе я совсем недавно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Приходится каждый раз писать

правильнее, наверно, дать возможность записывать в кэш самому http-серверу.

т.е., выполните:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/projectname/app/cache
```

а затем, для очистки кэша, запускайте команду от имени пользователя *www-data*, а не *root*:

```
$ sudo -u www-data php app/console cache:clear --env=dev(либо prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я к сожалению понятия не имею, что за симфония2.
Я правильно понимаю, что кеш - это некая папка, куда работающее под апачем приложение что то пишет, собственно для этого и нужны права.
Тогда предлагаю чистку кеша запускать без sudo или даже под судо с правами апача, т.е. `sudo -g www-data` и может еще пользователя владельцев файла так-же апачевского поставить. В итоге файлы сходу будут с нужными правами и не нужно будет их править.
По поводу prod/dev и DirectoryIndex информации для решения не достаточно. Например, prod и dev живут на одном домене, просто пути к папкам разные или там поддомены (тогда возможна проблема с конфигами и собственно тем самым DirectoryIndex)
Что мне подсказывает, что нам надо открывать чат и подробно общаться, после чего подредактировать вопрос-ответ что бы могло пригодиться сообществу.